# Opening outlook data file with batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, outlook

I am trying to make a batch file to open Outlook and all of my archive files along with it. I am getting an error saying `Outlook data files must be opened from within Outlook`. The code I have used is below:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE"
start OUTLOOK.EXE
cd "Z:\OUTLOOK ARCHIVES"
start "" "Z:\OUTLOOK ARCHIVES\Inbox 2010.pst"
```

Is it possible to open `.pst` files using a batch file?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is not possible.  Outlook data files must be opened from within Outlook.  Reference:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other/outlook-data-file-problem/29def16b-0d22-460a-9c8e-8af59030ffec